# Why $\langle f,x \rangle<\alpha \langle f,x_0 \rangle$ for all $x\in F$ implies $\langle f,x\rangle=0$ for all $x\in F$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $F\subset E$ a subspace of the Banach space $E$. Suppose $\bar F\ne E$. Then, there is $f\in E'$, $f\ne 0$ s.t. $$\langle f,x\rangle=0,$$
for all $x\in F$. I recall that $E'$ is the topological dual.

The proof goes as follow :

Let $x_0\in E\backslash \bar F$. By Hahn-Banach, we can strictly separate $\{x_0\}$ and $\bar F$. Let $f\in E'$ with $f\ne 0$ and $\alpha \in\mathbb R$ s.t. $$\langle f,x \rangle <\alpha < \langle f,x_0 \rangle.\tag{e}$$
Therefore $\langle f,x \rangle =0$ for all $x\in F$.

My question : Why do we get $\langle f,x \rangle =0$ for all $x\in F$ ? Does it still hold if $(e)$ is replace by $$\langle f,x_0 \rangle <\alpha < \langle f,x \rangle,$$
for all $x \in F$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $\langle f,x\rangle <\alpha <\langle f,x_0\rangle$ holds for all $x \in F$. Since $F$ is a linear subspace we get $c\langle f,x\rangle <\alpha$ for all $c$. This implies $\langle f,x\rangle=0$. [ If $\langle f,x\rangle >0$ let $c \to \infty$ and if $\langle f,x\rangle <0$ let $c \to -\infty$ to get a  contradiction].